# Is there in iso or boost function pointer that has the same syntax as std::function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I was wondering if there is a lightweight version of std::function that works only for function pointers but doesnt have horrible :)  syntax like regular function pointers.

Aka something like this:

```
int square(int x)
{
return x*x;
}
//...
function_ptr<int (int)> = square;
```

Ofc bind and all other fancy stuff std::function supports will fail, but I am ok with that, if I need std::function I will use it.

Comment: Doesn't a typedef do?

Comment: I dont find typedefs readable, that is my opinion, i have seen a bunch of ppl typedefing maps and stuff...

Comment: Just trying to understand your question. What do you mean by `the same syntax as std::function`? And what's wrong with using `std::function` directly?

Comment: @TingL same syntax : <int (int)>            and nothing wrong with std::function, but it has overhead, function ptr is just 32/64bit ptr

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl So would you consider `auto` and `decltype` in the answers the same syntax? If not, what do you need the <int (int)> like syntax for?

Comment: decltype is ugly, auto is pretty. and like i said i "need" that syntax for readability...

Comment: There is nothing out of the box like that, but it should be easy to build... create a template that takes the signature and defines the member pointer internally as a type. Then create an alias: `template <typename Sig> using fnptr = FuncPtr<Sig>::type`. Now the devil is in the details, and if you want this fool proof you will need to do a bit of magic to discard invalid template arguments but it should not require more than 20-30 lines of code.

Comment: **well**, there is one out of the box, although it admits more things that you might want: `template <typename Sig> using ptr = typename std::add_pointer<Sig>::type;`, now `ptr<void (int)>` is really `void (*)(int)` which is the function pointer that you wished for... of course this is a catch all that will allow `ptr<int>` to mean `int*`, but that might be ok I guess if the name is `ptr` (and not `fnptr`) [I guess this *is* an answer]

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas [deffo]

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: You "need" it? That makes NoSenseAtAll

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what I meant by it is it would be nice to have it, but I can live without it. :) witout const and auto and STL I cant :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Ahem C++ Standard Library! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is for a template to tranform from *signature* to *pointer to function to signature*, that is, to add a pointer to the type. That is already done in the standard library:

```
std::add_pointer<X>::type
```

But since what you want is the *nicer* syntax, you can add a template alias:

```
template <typename T>
using ptr = typename std::add_pointer<T>::type;
```

Then you can use it directly in your container:

```
void f(int);
std::vector<ptr<void (int)>> v; // vector of pointers to functions taking `int`
v.push_back(&f);
```

Comment: here is a simple example if ppl are interested: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e00aa0b5833ade9a   really nice answer, tnx

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context you want to use this in, it could be as simple as `auto` and/or `decltype`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  auto f = square;
  std::cout << f(5) << std::endl;

  // define a type
  using F = decltype(&square);
  F g = square;
  std::cout << g(5) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: well if I want to have a vector of callbacks I would prefer not to have vector of typedef to some function signature, but vector<function_ptr<int(int)>> ... still nica A, +1

Answer (score 1):

You can write an *opaque* wrapper if you do not want to use `typedef` directly. A prototype implementation using variadic templates is as follows. The same technique can be extended to other callable objects such as lambdas.

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
struct function_ptr {};

template<class R, class... Args>
struct function_ptr<R(Args...)>{
  typedef R (*funcType)(Args...);
  function_ptr(funcType f) : _f(f) {}
  funcType _f;
  R operator()(Args... args) { return _f(args...);}
};

int square(int x) {
  return x*x;
}

int main() {
  function_ptr<int (int)> f = square;
  std::cout << f(2) << std::endl;
}
```